# Magento 1.9 reindex error - catalog search sql violation 1064

Tags: sql, magento-1.9, reindex

Sorry I am a complete novice.  I am getting this error from my exception report in magento. If anyone can tell me how to fix it i'd appreciate it.

> 2016-06-06T19:03:22+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message:
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE
>   (main.parent_id = '955') AND (ciss.stock_status = 1)' at line 2, query
>   was:

```
SELECT `main`.`product_id` FROM `catalog_product_super_link` AS `main`  
INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `ciss` ON
 ciss.product_id = main.product_id AND ciss.website_id =  
 WHERE (main.parent_id = '955') AND (ciss.stock_status = 1)
```

Comment: Seems your  query is incorrect there is a = where .. could by you have omitted a part .. please provide the right  code

Comment: The code is magento's default code for reindexing the catalog search. I haven't edited the code. I believe that this error may be linked to a custom attribute set in magento, i will let you know.

Comment: In sql a query with AND ciss.website_id =   where is sintactically wrong .. .. you can  change this code ?